# Trying to write a Fluid App userscript to disable notion sidebar auto popup behavior

Tags: javascript, userscripts

## Edit - working solution

Trying to disable the javascript event was a no-go, instead I ended up adding an additional element into the DOM that toggled the visibility of the sidebar with css which worked. It's not the prettiest solution as I'm just learning, but it does solve the problem.

It doesn't work as a Fluid userscript but does work as a Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey script in the browser. [Full code is on Github](https://github.com/Roznoshchik/Notion-no-sidebar) - would love someone with more knowledge to improve on it.

## Original Post

I'm a newbie in JS but am trying to learn by doing.

I use notion and am very annoyed by the sidebar that pops up whenever the mouse hovers over the left side of the app.

I read somewhere that I can use the Fluid app to push userscripts and that it might be possible to disable that functionality with custom styling.

But I can't seem to figure out how to get either the JS or CSS to disable mouseover events.

I think I found where the event is being listened for, but I'm not sure about next steps for how to remove that listener funtion, or to stop the function call.

This is where I think the event is being triggered, can anyone advise?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wasn't able to solve this using the initial methods and ended up trying a totally different approach which worked.

Wasn't able to figure out how to get it to work in Fluid App yet, but I did manage a greasemonkey userscript.

Instead of trying to change the event listener function, I just control the visibility of the sidebar.

I add a button into the DOM, and give that button a trigger that toggles notions sidebar visibility. Click the button and the sidebar is invisible and nothing pops as you hover over the left side.

It's not the prettiest solution, because it doesn't remove notion's existing button for the sidebar, and if you don't minimize the sidebar with notion's own button, then the formatting can be a bit wonky, but as a hack it totally works.

I'm very new to JS and coding in general, so this is prob very inefficient. But if it helps anyone, here's the [code in Github](https://github.com/Roznoshchik/Notion-no-sidebar) – I would love for someone to help me make this better.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a mousemove capturing listener to a container of the element with the listener. On mousemove, if the target (element to which the event is being dispatched) is a descendant of the element with the page listener you want not to fire, call `stopPropagation` on the event.

For example, in the below code, the page script tries to color an element when it or one of its descendants is hovered, but the second part (which can go into a userscript) will prevent that:

```js
// Page script:
nested.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  nested.style.color = 'red';
});

// Userscript:
outer.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if (e.target.closest('#nested')) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
}, true);
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  outer
  <div id="nested">
    nested
    <div id="inner">
      inner
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I see what you're saying. 

This would also work if the elements don't have ids but only classes?

Would I just replace #nested for .nested in that case?

Comment: Yes, as long as you can identify a unique selector, which is almost always possible.

Comment: I tried the following but it isn't working. 
What might be the issue?


`notion-app.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if (e.target.closest('.notion-sidebar-container')) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
}, true);`

Comment: `notion-app` is invalid syntax - you need to select the element with Javascript

Comment: `var x = Document.getElementById('notion-app')

x.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if (e.target.closest('.notion-sidebar-container')) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
}, true);`

Trying, but still not working - maybe I'm targeting the wrong event? 
In the source code, the div that actually calls the event doesn't have an id or class. Is this the issue?

Thanks so much for taking the time to answer.

Comment: `Document` is wrong - you need to use `document` - always check the console for errors to see what's going wrong

Comment: Thanks  I made that edit and still not getting the functionality I'm looking for

Comment: Any console errors? Can you post a link to the site so I can reproduce the problem too?

Comment: https://www.notion.so/Story-Site-b95ac59deca8491da2c4baca40c1be6a

No console errors that I can understand.

Comment: Thanks, though I don't see a `.notion-sidebar-container` on that page, how can I get it to appear so I can test it out? That's what the page listener is attached to, right?

Comment: Here's a screen recording of the interaction and what i'm seeing. 

Maybe this helps?

https://www.loom.com/share/154dd4f654444088a699d4e9045fa71a

Comment: The code you already posted, once fixed per discussion above: `document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if (e.target.closest('.notion-sidebar-container')) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
}, true);` really looks like it should do it, unless something's patched (and broken) `addEventListener`, which is very unlikely. If something's still getting through, either the page listener is attached to a completely separate element, or the page is listening to a different event.

Comment: But without being able to reproduce the problem for myself, I can't see what the issue is or fix it, how do I get the problematic sidebar to appear? I don't see anything on the left when I load that page (or the `notion-sidebar-container` or anything like that)

Comment: If it's at all helpful is it possible to somehow use `document.getElementById("myDIV").removeEventListener("mousemove", myFunction);' 

I seem to have found the code that calls this in their JS

https://pastebin.com/dptUkTd0

the open call is at the very bottom of that code.

Comment: No, you need a reference to the function in order to remove it via `removeEventListener`, but you don't have such a reference. You can also monkeypatch `addEventListener` yourself at the beginning of pageload with `@run-at document-start`, and prevent the bad listener from being added, but that's much too complicated for what should be fixed pretty easily with a capturing listener

Comment: Maybe double check that your userscript is actually running? Add a `console.log` inside your handler to see if it fires on mousemove

Comment: I was able to see the eventlistener that i initially added to the main div. The subsequent stopPropogation didn't seem to work.

Comment: So I was able to select that element in the console specifically and try what you suggested, but I'm getting an error. 

`var x = temp1.firstChild;

temp1.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if (e.target.closest(x)) {
    e.stopPropogation();
  }
}, true);`

Is what I tried. 

And the error I get is: SyntaxError: Element.closest: '[object HTMLDivElement]' is not a valid selector

I guess I can't pass in a variable to e.closest() ?

Comment: If you want to check whether a node contains another, use `.contains`, eg `x.contains(e.target)`, but the `.closest` method *should* work. Without a [MCVE] of the problem, it's impossible to say what the solution might be

Comment: I'd love to give you a minimal reproducible example but it isn't possible without being logged in to the app.

Don't know what I can do in this case.